# What do King Bowser's escape potions actually do?

Tags: tv, super-mario-brothers

In the TV show Super Mario Bros Super Show-Bowser, after being defeated, usually escapes in 1 form or another. I saw him throw the red potions from the game(which he escapes with)-which in the game lead to SubCon-where you can collect coins or mushrooms. What's the deal with Bowsers potions? If it is to SubCon-why can't the Mario Bros. chase after him?